# How can I pass variables between ruby scripts?

Tags: ruby

I am mostly interested in the theory of this than an actual code solution. How can I have one main ruby script invoking other scripts and sharing variables between each other? I am a bit confused.. Do I need to use environmental vars, session vars, methods, models, controllers, what is the best way to do it!!?

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you have a `script.rb`, which contains this:

```
$var = :value
def get; A end
load 'another_script.rb'
get  # Will it succeed?
```

When you run `ruby script.rb`, you spawn a Ruby process which will read the contents of `script.rb` and execute every line. The Ruby interpreter has an *execution state* which holds information such as object data, the variables that reference them, which scope they belong to, which method you're currently in and so much more.

When the interpreter reads the `$var = :value` line, it modifies its own state. It stores a global variable which references the newly-created symbol object. Next, it defines a method which will return the value referenced by the `A` constant. Calling it at this point will raise a `NameError`, since the constant does not exist. When it reaches the `load 'another_script.rb'` line, it is analogous to running `ruby another_script.rb`, except no second process is started. The contents of the script are read and interpreted *within the same execution context*.

Suppose `another_script.rb` contains the following:

```
$var = :changed
class A; end
```

The `$var` variable, which previously referenced the `:value` symbol, will now reference the `:changed` symbol. Then, a `Class` object will be created and assigned to the new `A` constant.

*After* loading this script, the call to `get` will succeed. Another implication is that *order matters*. For example:

```
load 'another_script.rb'
$var = :value
```

Whatever `another_script.rb` set `$var` to will be lost since it will be overridden immediately after it has finished executing.

No matter how many scripts you `load`, `require` or `eval`, as long as they are running on the same process, they will *always* share the same data. [Only local variables will not be shared between files](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load). Things get complicated when you want to share data between two *different* Ruby interpreters:

```
ruby script.rb &
ruby another_script.rb &
```

In that case, you have to use [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Awesome Matheus :) Thank you so much for your valuable help!! Best answer over here by far and with nice example :) Thanks and to the rest of the guys who answered, this website is the simply AWESOME!

Comment: @Xwris, I'm glad you found it useful. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) which ultimately answered your question.

Comment: I have a specific situation: I have one script which instantiates clients to hit a third party service.  I have another script which needs to invoke those clients (the clients are from the third party SDK).  Should I load or ‘require’ or ‘require_relative’ the script?  I did so but still get an error

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by *invoking*.

Generally when "*a script invokes another script*" it's basically the same as one "process starting another process". So there you would use inter-process communcation, not really specific to Ruby.. Yes, simple things like environment variables are one way to pass info down, but might consider files, sockets, etc..

OTOH, if you want to *use* Ruby code from in one "script" (.rb) file in another, you load/require it as the first answer pointed out.
This makes the methods (def f), constants(CTE), instance variables(@f) and global variables($G) available in the file you're loading from;  but not the local variables (like x=3).

In special cases, you can want to use 'eval' to access local variables too - but I don't think that's applicable in your scenario.

Answer (score 3):

If you want two Ruby processes to communicate (even if they are running on different machines), then [Druby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html) is the built in way.

Comment: I think for the DRuby to share variables, we need to create the variables on the server and then it can be used across clients (ruby scripts). I could not find a way where client-script1  creates an object, saves it in the dRB server and client-script2 uses the same object. Thoughts?